# Assigned the right constant values to its corresponding rows in query

Tags: sql, database

i have my query which i declare 2 constant values suppose 112 and 78,so its display as 2 columns namely  Store and Supermarket and i have another column name customers_type who usually do their shopping to both Store and Supermarket.So my constant values for Store is 112 and Supermarket is 78, and my last column Customers_type has 3 types, oldies,youth and children..for oldies and youth both have the same constant values,112 and children has 78.
the problem when i run my query the values for both store(112) and Supermarket(78) are display in all of my rows but not assigned to the right rows if store(112) then it should be assigned  only to oldies and youths and Supermarket(78) to assigned only to Children

i want my solution to be like the one below

```
store | supermarket  |customers_type

112   |   0          |       oldies

112   |   0          |      youth

0     |  78          |      children
```

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without seeing 1) The table schema 2) Example data which will produce the results above and 3) What queries you have tried and why they didn't work.

Comment: What is the query that you are running?